# Linearized Fit to Data

Tags: java

I'm creating a class to describe a "zigzag line" fit to a set of data. It implements my interface Fittable, which just contains `evaluate()` (I have mulitple kinds of curves that all implement this interface). I created the private inner class `Node` to describe a vertex. It will give the slope going to the left and the slope to the right.

I'm doing a double-check in `evaluate()`. I am determining the value based off both the `floor()` and `ceiling()` values. However, sometimes I get values that don't match up and the `IllegalStateException` is being thrown. This is because the values for the slopes aren't the same, which lends me to believe that there's a problem with my while loop in the constructor, but I need a fresh set of eyes.

Of course, optimizations are always welcome.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 *
 * @author gobernador
 */
public class LinearizedFit implements Fittable {

    private TreeSet<Node> data;

    public LinearizedFit(double[][] input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (int r = 0; r < input.length; r++) {
            if (input[r].length != 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data must be in a smooth, two-column format.");
            }
        }

        data = new TreeSet(new NodeComparator());

        for (double[] coords : input) {
            data.add(new Node(coords[0], coords[1]));
        }

        Iterator<Node> iter = data.iterator();
        Node last, node = null, next = iter.next();

        while (true) {
            last = node;
            node = next;

            try {
                next = iter.next();
                node.slopeRight = slope(node, next);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                next.slopeLeft = slope(last, node);
                next.slopeRight = slope(last, node);
                break;
            }

            if (last != null) {
                node.slopeLeft = slope(last, node);
            } else {
                node.slopeLeft = slope(node, next);
            }
        }
    }

    public double evaluate(final double x) {

        Node thisNode = new Node(x);
        Node floor = data.floor(thisNode);
        Node ceiling = data.ceiling(thisNode);

        double d1, d2;
        try {
            d1 = floor.y + (floor.slopeRight * (x - floor.x));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return ceiling.y + (ceiling.slopeLeft * (x - ceiling.x));
        }

        try {
            d2 = ceiling.y + (ceiling.slopeLeft * (x - ceiling.x));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return d1;
        }

        if (d1 != d2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bad information");
        }
        return d1;
    }

    private double slope(final Node n1, final Node n2) {
        return (n2.y - n1.y) / (n2.x - n1.x);
    }

    private class Node {

        final double x;
        final double y;
        double slopeLeft;
        double slopeRight;

        Node(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        Node(double x) {
            this(x, 0);
        }
    }

    private class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {

        public int compare(final Node o1, final Node o2) {
            if (o1.x < o2.x) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o1.x > o2.x) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        LinearizedFit lf = new LinearizedFit(new double[][]{{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}});
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(-1));
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(0.5));
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(1.5));
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(3));
    }
}
```

EDIT: added a main method

I expect with this main method to get an output

> -1.0
>   0.5
>   0.5
>   -1.0

but instead I get

> -1.0
>   0.5
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad information
>       at mypackage.LinearizedFit.evaluate(LinearizedFit.java:70)
>       at mypackage.LinearizedFit.main(LinearizedFit.java:113)
>   Java Result: 1

---

Edit: SOLVED: the class below represents the working version

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 *
 * @author gobernador
 */
public class LinearizedFit implements Fittable {

    private TreeSet<Node> data;

    public LinearizedFit(double[][] input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (int r = 0; r < input.length; r++) {
            if (input[r].length != 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data must be in a smooth, two-column format.");
            }
            data.add(new Node(input[r][0], input[r][1]));
        }

        Iterator<Node> iter = data.iterator();
        Node last, node = null, next = iter.next();

        do {
            last = node;
            node = next;
            next = iter.next();

            node.slopeRight = slope(node, next);

            if (last != null) {
                node.slopeLeft = slope(last, node);
            } else {
                node.slopeLeft = slope(node, next);
            }
        } while (iter.hasNext());

        next.slopeLeft = slope(node, next);
        next.slopeRight = slope(node, next);
    }

    public double evaluate(final double x) {

        Node thisNode = new Node(x);
        Node floor = data.floor(thisNode);
        Node ceiling = data.ceiling(thisNode);

        double d1, d2;
        if (floor != null) {
            d1 = floor.y + (floor.slopeRight * (x - floor.x));
        } else {
            return ceiling.y + (ceiling.slopeLeft * (x - ceiling.x));
        }

        if (ceiling != null) {
            d2 = ceiling.y + (ceiling.slopeLeft * (x - ceiling.x));
        } else {
            return d1;
        }

        if (d1 != d2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bad information");
        }
        return d1;
    }

    private double slope(final Node n1, final Node n2) {
        return (n2.y - n1.y) / (n2.x - n1.x);
    }

    private static class Node {

        final double x;
        final double y;
        double slopeLeft;
        double slopeRight;

        Node(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        Node(double x) {
            this(x, 0);
        }
    }

    private static class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {

        public int compare(final Node o1, final Node o2) {
            if (o1.x < o2.x) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o1.x > o2.x) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        LinearizedFit lf = new LinearizedFit(new double[][]{{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}});
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(-1));
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(0.5));
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(1.5));
        System.out.println(lf.evaluate(3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [don't catch `NullPointerExceptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586290/is-catching-a-null-pointer-exception-a-code-smell). Not only is it slightly more inefficient, it's a terrible code smell. Instead, do this:

```
if(floor != null){
    d1 = floor.y + (floor.slopeRight * (x - floor.x));
} else {
    return ceiling.y + (ceiling.slopeLeft * (x - ceiling.x));
}
```

Second, if your nested classes don't need access to the outer class, go ahead and make it a static nested class. Just add the `static` modifier.

```
private static class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
```

Third, You loop over the data twice at the beginning. Once to verify integrity and another to add it to your tree. Why not combine the two?

```
data = new TreeSet(new NodeComparator());
for (double[] coords : input) {
    if (coords.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data must be in a smooth, two-column format.");
    }
    data.add(new Node(coords[0], coords[1]));
}
```

Finally, using an exception to detect the end of the set makes me nervous. I would rewrite that using `iter.hasNext()`.

```
if(iter.hasNext()){
    next = iter.next();
    node.slopeRight = slope(node, next);
} else {
    next.slopeLeft = slope(last, node);
    next.slopeRight = slope(last, node);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm still getting unexpected results. See my edited question for more error information.

Answer (score 3):

Floating point values are not precise and you compare two doubles with `!=`.

See:

- *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*
- [How to compare two double values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java)

Some other notes:

1. ```
   data = new TreeSet(new NodeComparator());
   ```

   should be

   ```
   data = new TreeSet<Node>(new NodeComparator());
   ```
2. *@Danny Kirchmeier* has already mentioned the bad practice with `NoSuchElementException` and `NullPointerException`. I would like to add another reference to it: *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 57: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions*.